# Embed rocker switch in desk - Safety/Fire Hazard?

Tags: electrical, united-kingdom

I've just bought a few of these (photo below) rocker switches (rated 16A/250VAC) with the intent of embedding them directly in a plywood desk. They'll be soldered inline between the wall socket and a 6 way extension cable to allow me to physically turn on/off the connected equipment without having to scramble around under the desk to turn them off at the wall.

[image: rocker switch]

I was going to 3d print an enclosure to keep all of the live wires tucked away, but a friend mentioned that I might need to be careful as the bare contacts (though I could heat shrink them) would be very close to the wood and the 3d printed plastic, which might pose a fire risk.

That sounds like a reasonable concern, though the actual switching mechanism is enclosed within the plastic body of the switch, so any momentary arcing should be already contained.

I don't really want a full face plate (to embed the switch in) on the top of my desk (especially as I will have 3 of these), as I'd like it as minimal as possible, so I was thinking I could route in a junction box ([something like this](https://www.screwfix.com/p/chocbox-30a-connector-box-50-x-28-x-28mm/54936)) and cut a hole in it so the bottom of the switch pokes through; just so it's all contained properly.

I'd just like some input on whether people think it's a good idea to embed a backbox/junction box in the underside of the desk, whether it's nothing to be concerned about and I can just 3d print an enclosure and have the live contacts near the wood, or whether anyone can thing of a better option altogether?

Thanks.

Comment: Just to clarify: are you in the UK with 220/240v?

Comment: I am in the UK, yeah.

Comment: Most areas require some sort of approved / rated junction box for line voltage connections and switches.

Comment: @JACK the regulations in the UK would require that for fixed wiring (leading to wall sockets, ceiling lights etc.) but desk-mounted sockets that plug into the wall aren't covered by those wiring regs.  A commercial product with flexible wiring would be subject to a different set of rules, which we can try to emulate

Comment: I wouldn't count on a 3D printed box to contain sparks/fire should something go wrong, unless you're 100% certain about the plastic you're using. While _code_ may not require that the box be fireproof, common sense should. Often times, plastics emit very toxic fumes when burning, so even if the fire doesn't escape the box immediately, the fumes may get you first.

Comment: Also, "I'd just like some input on whether people think it's a good idea to..." is asking for opinions which is explicitly [off-topic](https://diy.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask).

Comment: Thanks for the comments. As I mentioned below on Chris's answer, I think I will go the project box route, but it's still interesting to get insight on the other options.
WRT your last point @FreeMan, I think it may just be poor phrasing on my part. I could (or should) have asked it a different way to avoid the opinion aspect.

Comment: Why not just get a power strip with a long cord?

Comment: @Huesmann - The socket is on the back wall (under the desk) and I'd also like to have all of the cables plugged in under the desk, but still able to switch each strip on/off from above the desk, so a longer cord unfortunately won't solve my issue.

Comment: If this was my project, low voltage relay triggers and listed junction boxes would be preferred.

Comment: @AloysiusDefenestrate - I did consider relays, but it just felt a bit over complicated for what I wanted to do. Thanks for the suggestion though!

Comment: @OdinX you could build a box/platform/shelf under your desk and secure the power strip on it.  Plug your stuff in.  Cut a slot (or a pair of holes) in the desk right above the switch on the power strip.  Build a tube the shape of the power switch between the strip and bottom of the desk.  Get some wood or plastic dowels, depending on the size/shape of the hole(s), and stick them in the holes, to use as extensions for the switch.

Comment: Haha, I like it; thinking outside the box!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If anything is getting hot enough to pose a fire risk just by being near wood or 3d-printed plastic, you've got big problems, and a fire risk even in a proper enclosure.  Arcing isn't the concern; you won't ignite any of these materials with even a big spark.

That's not to say there's nothing to worry about. A poor connection carrying high current can start fires so you need to make sure you don't end up doing that. I'd use a proper project box, which you could rout in from the back.  Project boxes / plastic enclosures from the like of RS are easier to work with than those moulded terminal boxes, and tidier.  The downside is they don't usually  have any strain relief built in so you need to add that.

I would either use heatshrink over soldered joins, or insulated crimps (pull-tested to make sure they're secure), and I would definitely cable tie the wires together as close as possible to the connections, such that if one came loose it couldn't get anywhere.

Further notes:

- In some jurisdictions such DIY electrical work has insurance implications, even if it never causes a problem
- If your desk is anything like mine, anything set into the top should be considered in the light of spill hazards.  I'd mount switches in the side personally, because I'd want any in the top to be waterproof (plus I'd bury them under paper, tools etc.).  What I've actually done is rigged an extension lead with a solid state relay to turn it off when I power down the PC.
- Have you considered using a 3/4/6-gang light switch with a suitable back box? That could be all metal and earthed, or all plastic an not earthed.

Comment: Great answer, thanks for your thoughts. Spills isn't something I had considered either. Perhaps moving to the side/front of the desk is something I'll give some thought to. Aside from spills and ease of use, you don't think 3d printing an enclosure/the wood is anything to be concerned about? I think I will go the project box route, but more out of curiosity than anything.

Comment: My 3d-printing experience is of designing and using PLA parts, but not printing them myself.  PLA has to be quite thick for much strength, and is always brittle compared to moulded ABS (typical for plastic project boxes). I can't recall he cost of filament, but with the need for thicker walls, you'll need quite a lot of it.  I've mounted mains in wooden enclosures for personal projects before, with a fair bit of  clearance

Answer (score 0):

A 3D printed box may be conductive and the box libked is not rated, and again may not be suitable.

I  would go with smart switches to control the appliances. And you can either control them with your phone, PC, Alexa, Siri or build a box  of low voltage switches.

Comment: Home 3-d printing won't be conductive, because it's hard to make plastic conductive, and 3-d printing metals isn't something you'll do at home